# Docker is not exporting env var

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have built an image from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins

RUN export http_proxy=http://user:pass@x.x.x.x:port

#more things
```

But when I enter in the container (via exec /bin/bash), `http_proxy` is not exported.

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason for using `export`, Docker has built-in support for using [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) in a Dockerfile:

```
ENV http_proxy='http://user:pass@x.x.x.x:port'
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Now, I have realized that I was using wrong syntax of ENV command. Thanks!

Comment: In case you were wondering, the reason the `RUN export ...` command didn't work is because the `export` command doesn't persist results across shell/bash sessions. Anything exported using `RUN` will not be available when you exec in or startup the container image.